# Do the 5-byte and 9-byte binary zip comments at the end of .jar files serve some purpose, or are they likely due to an uninitialized buffer bug?

Tags: java, kotlin, jar, zip, file-format

`.jar` files as used by Java and Kotlin are a specialization of the `.zip` file format. They most contain certain files and/or directories, and they may only use a restricted subset of the full features of zip files.

While writing my own zip file handling code to educate myself, I noticed that about 2,000 `.jar` files on my Mac end with zip archive comment fields containing unprintable bytes. They are all either 5-byte or 9-byte comments, they all conform to the zip file format specification for comments, meaning they are not simply appended junk, they don't occur in other other files that are based on the zip archive format, and they look like they share some internal format.

Firstly, I know they're not simply appended rubbish since the zip format spec says there is a 2-byte little-endian field specifying the length of the comment, and then the comment follows. The files I'm talking about all have this length field that matches the size of the subsequent binary data in the comment field. This does not rule out being junk, but would require the code that creates them to count it as a field with a known size, rather than simply being added by any random tool the file may have been processed by.

You can see these fields using the `-v` switch of either `zipinfo` or `zipdetails`, both of which I believe come with macOS. It will be at the top of `zipinfo` output and at the bottom of `zipdetails` output.

Here are some examples of each kind:

**5 byte comments**

- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlinc_allopen-compiler-plugin.jar
  `{ 3, 70, 104, 0, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlinc_kotlin-jps-common.jar
  `{ 3, 36, 96, 5, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/javaslang.jar
  `{ 3, 140, 63, 29, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/javax-inject.jar
  `{ 3, 213, 10, 0, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlinc_kotlin-compiler-fe10.jar
  `{ 3, 63, 68, 73, 3 }`

Note that the first byte is *always* `3` and the last byte is usually `0` but *never* greater than `9`.

**9 byte comments**

- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-compiler-fe10-for-ide-1.6.20-release-275.jar
  `{ 1, 199, 35, 0, 0, 58, 44, 65, 3 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/javaslang-2.0.6.jar
  `{ 1, 21, 1, 0, 0, 112, 110, 28, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-compiler-ir-for-ide-1.6.20-release-275.jar
  `{ 1, 168, 10, 0, 0, 187, 137, 30, 1 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-compiler-common-for-ide-1.6.20-release-275.jar
  `{ 1, 247, 13, 0, 0, 200, 187, 235, 0 }`

Note that now the first byte is *always* `1` and the last byte is still usually `0` and still *never* greater than `9`.

On my whole system there are only two other zip-format files with binary comments of sizes other than 5 or 9 bytes. They are also both `.jar` files though and have 6-byte comments:

- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/tmp/patch-update/log4j.jar
  `{ 104, 11, 220, 104, 58, 0 }`
- /Users/hippietrail/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/tmp/patch-update/jna.jar
  `{ 104, 11, 220, 104, 61, 0 }`

Does anybody know if these fields are meaningful or able to confirm that they're junk caused by a bug?

Comment: That's a really interesting observation.  Checked my Ubuntu install but I can't find any jar files with comments. Don't have Kotin installed though. Would be surprized if these comments are accidental. but you never know. Downloaded the Kotlin source, but nothing is jumping out.

Comment: @pmqs The source is in Zig, a fun new compiled language. I can post it in a gist or pastebin if you want to try it out. I might have some Swift source that does almost the same thing too. I've definitely seen the same binary comments in .jar files that I think are for Java rather than Kotlin too.

Comment: Hmm, if I remember correctly Java ultimately uses the `zipfile` class for creation of JAR files, but I don't think it has an API that allows writing of the zip comments. Wonder if this is a post-processing step that is applied to the JAR files after creation? Don't understand the connection with zig (assume this is zig?  https://github.com/ziglang/zig) , but then I don't know much about Kotin either. What us the connection? If there is a link, to something then yes, please post it.

Comment: @pmqs. I found these things because I'm writing my own zip file parsing code. I'm going to post a nicely formatted dump of all the relevant .far files on my system to pastebin in a few minutes. I even saw some files with "groovy" in their path. OK here's the list: https://pastebin.com/wuzZwHn3

Comment: Thanks -- I see lots of JetBrains in that list -- will see if I can get some time to download the source & see if there is anything lurking. [full disclosure - I'm the author of the `zipdetails` code you mentioned using]

Comment: @pmqs: Oh cool! I actually had one file that my tool showed something odd in and zipdetails complained the file was cut short, but the end of the file looks fine, testing  with zip and unzipping it also seemed to work fine. So I thought it was either a bug in a corner case in zipdetails or corrupted zip file no other tool detected. I'll have to rack my brains to remember just what it was and let you know!

Comment: @pmqs: Yes the very last file in the pastebin is the one that fails in zipdetails: IdeaIC2021.3/plugins/Kotlin.zip - error msg is `Unexpecded END at offset 0735434A, value 00000012` - I looked the other day to try to find somewhere to download it so I could investigate of file a bug report. I'll try again now...

Comment: Downloaded community IltelliJ and seeing jar files with binary comments just like you reported. Will have a dig tomorrow if I get some free time. Regarding the zipdetails error, you could try the latest development version from https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails/blob/develop/bin/zipdetails. If still seeing a problem, can you create a ticket at https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails/issues please?

Comment: @pmqs: I had a bug report all typed out before I tested your new version. It works with the new version which reports `735434A 00038E4 ...         UNEXPECTED PADDING` where the old version failed. This is right between the last local header and the first central header. It still reports the 9-byte binary comment, which may or may not fit in with those in the `.jar` files...?

Comment: good to hear that worked. 14k is quite a large amount of padding! Doubt it is related to the binary comments, but you never know.

Comment: @pmqs: I might suggest such things be labelled "unreferenced" since it could be padding on purpose but it could just be due to a bug. It seems to be full of random bytes. The two might be related only due to both being caused by buggy code outputting unintialized buffers?

Comment: It may be intentional padding in this case, but from a strict compliance perspective it is a badly formed zip file. Will keep your suggestion of "unreferenced" in mind